# Erlang Mnesia not working with size one record

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have been trying to make Mnesia work with records of size one, where the key is the value itself, but it does not seem to work.

*Console:*

```
Eshell V7.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c(mnesiac).
{ok,mnesiac}
2> mnesiac:in
init/0    insert/1  
2> mnesiac:init().
{aborted,{bad_type,player,{attributes,[id]}}}
```

*Code:*

```
  1 -module(mnesiac).
  2 -compile(export_all).
  3 
  4 -record(player, {id}).
  5 
  6 init() ->
  7     mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
  8     mnesia:start(),
  9     mnesia:create_table(player,
 10         [ {disc_copies, [node()] },
 11              {attributes,
 12                 record_info(fields,player)} ]).
 13 
 14 insert(Id) ->
 15     Fun = fun() ->
 16         mnesia:write( #player{id=Id})
 17     end,
 18     mnesia:transaction(Fun).
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
(As another problem, we could only make mnesia work with records of 3 or more fields in another program, so I'm thinking there is something wrong somewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to store a record with only one field in a Mnesia table.  That is mentioned in the documentation, though perhaps not where you would look first, but in the description of [`mnesia:create_table/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#create_table-2):

> - `{attributes, AtomList}` is a list of the attribute names for the records that are supposed to populate the table. Default is `[key, val]`. **The table must at least have one extra attribute in addition to the key.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you very much! We did in fact look at the documentation and searched trhough it but none of us noticed that sentence. We first had problems with records with two attributes, maybe that is why. Thanks for the help :D